# how to sort objects by value length in powershell

Tags: powershell

how can I get the object with smaller name size from an array?

$a

Name                               Value
----                               -----
name                               A
name                               AAAA
name                               BB
name                               AAAAAA

$a | get-smaller -property "name" ==> should return the object with name = A

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$a | sort { $_.value.length }  | select -expand value -first 1
```

Answer (score 2):

To sort file input.txt by lines length and put the result to output.txt:

```
Get-Content -Path input.txt | sort { $_.length } > output.txt
```

1. Result is not ASCII/case-sensitive sorted
2. There might be problem with different encodings - lines are omitted
3. Result is normally UCS-2 Little Endian